How can i onbly allow certain users in Azure to access a VM?
I have a VM in azure and i restrict via Ip address. This is not full proof as ip addresses can change if they have a dhcp server.
So is there a way i can create a group within Azure and assign that group to the VM to only allow that the members in that group to access the VM ?


How can i only allow certain users in Azure to access a VM?

To grant specific users in Azure access to a VM, you can follow the steps outlined below.

Note: User or Group restrictions in Azure can only be applied if the VM is joined to Azure AD.


Create a group in Azure AD by navigating to Microsoft Entra ID > Groups > New Group



After creating a group, you can add members who require access to the VM by navigating to Groups > VM_allowed_users > Members.



Assign the role to group to access the VM

To allow a user to sign in to the VM over RDP, you must assign the Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login role to the Virtual Machine resource, refer this link for more details.
Go to VM > Access control (IAM) > Add role assignment > Select the role > under Members > select the group : VM_allowed_users.


Once the role is assigned to the group, only the users within that group will have access to the VM..


I have tried this and it seems there is something missing as i can access the machine no problem whether through rdp or a browser url ?

Do you mean. If users outside of the group are also accessing the virtual machine?

So what i mean i that if a user browses to the machine to a port where a service is running then they can access it normally. Problem is i cant use ip addresses as they are running through a DHCP server and change regularly and i will need to keep adding ip addresses which is not practical

when i Go to VM > Access control (IAM) > Add role assignment > Select the role > under Members > select the group : VM_allowed_users.   What role do i select from the list , is it virtual machine login , as these users naviagte via a link like https:///:<port_number>

You can assign either the Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login role based on your requirements. When the user navigates to https://ip/servicename, is this using a private or public IP?

If public IP is aceesing from outside,you can block all traffic except your network address in NSG rules,there is a option to specific the whole range address in NSG.

So what i have is  users in the company accessing the VM , they are Entra users. So they have an ip address , but their ip address can change so i want to use Entra Id user name . I only want those users to be abl;e to access the VM

Hi @Melissa, Could you please provide a detailed description of your issue?
